# How do I match variables in PHP?

Tags: php, html, post, get

For class, I need to create a fake online dating site that matches people together based on variables. The singles.txt file contains the user's name, gender(M of F), age, personality type, favorite OS, seeking genders (M,F or MF) and min/max seeking age, separated by commas. The code below is the checkboxes from my index.php/signup page.

```
    <input type="checkbox" name="seekMale" value="M"/>Male
    <input type="checkbox" name="seekFemale" value="F"/>Female
```

The code below is from my matches.php. I can't figure out of to get the seeking gender part to work. If the new user is a male seeking females, only females seeking males should be displayed, etc. Any help would be SO appreciated.

```
    <?php
    $name = $_GET["name"];//get the name parameter
    $people = file("singles.txt", FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);//load the data from singles.txt
    ?>

    <h1>Matches for <?= $name ?></h1>        
    <?php 
    foreach($people as $person) {
        list($person_name, $gender, $age, $type, $os, $min, $max) = explode(",", $person);
        if($person_name == $name) {
            foreach($people as $match) {
                list($match_name, $match_gender, $match_age, $match_type, 
            $match_os, $match_min, $match_max) = explode(",", $match);
                if($gender != $match_gender && $os == $match_os && $match_min <= $age && 
            $match_max >= $age && $min <= $match_age && $max >= $match_age && similar_text ($type, $match_type) >= 1) {
    ?>
```

Comment: You are matching 1 != 1 case here.

Comment: You are not returning anything in here?

Comment: That 1 != 1 gender one is for straight people. I don't even know what to do with my variables or anything of "seekMale" and "seekFemale" or something to make it bi/lesbian friendly.